# "Natural" measure on the set of measurable functions between measure spaces

Tags: measure-theory, soft-question

Let $X,Y$ be [measure spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_space) and let $M(X,Y)$ denote the set of measurable functions $f: X\to Y$. Is there a "natural" way to define a measure on $M(X,Y)$?

Comment: What would you consider "natural"?  There is always counting measure...

Comment: Take $X=[0,1]$ with the Lebesgue measure, and $Y=\mathbb{R}$. You get a pretty big infinite-dimensional space. There is no Lebesgue-type measure even on $L_2([0,1])$, and even Gaussian ones are supported on its extensions that involve distributions, not measurable functions. And they are not canonical anyway.

Comment: Good point,@RobertIsrael. Is there such a thing as a category of measurable spaces, and does it have something like [exponential objects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_object)?